# Is there an eslint rule for detecting unused class properties?

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I am working with an Angular project and my ESLint setup does not detect when a private class variable is unused, e.g.

```
@Component{...}
export class ExampleComponent {
  private exampleProperty: string
}
```

The private property above - `exampleProperty` will not be highlighted with the current ESLint setup that I have.

My `.eslintrc.json`:

```
{
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": ["projects/**/*"],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts"],
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": ["tsconfig.json", "e2e/tsconfig.json"],
        "createDefaultProgram": true
      },
      "env": { "browser": true, "jest": true },
      "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
          "error",
          { "prefix": "app", "style": "kebab-case", "type": "element" }
        ],
        "@angular-eslint/no-host-metadata-property": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/ban-types": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": [
          "error",
          { "argsIgnorePattern": "^_" }
        ],
        "no-case-declarations": "off",
        "no-console": ["error", { "allow": ["warn", "error"] }],
        "no-prototype-builtins": "off",
        "no-unused-vars": "off"
      }
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.html"],
      "extends": ["plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"],
      "rules": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I get the linter to pick this up?

Answer (score 5):

You can get **TypeScript** to pick this up for you, by turning on the `noUnusedLocals` option in `tsconfig.json`. ("Locals" apparently includes unused private properties, which are after all local to the class.)

[Here's a playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUnusedLocals=true#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4FEQoLZhLADCEBEAdsBfAN4BQcTcYUAlgG4ozByj6FgABSgQwwWAE8AXHDQx2FAOb1GzBJXlQArghjQAFCGla2ygJRwGzG3BgALNmgB0-AkRFiJMSXAC8cCAA3GpMAL70YUA) with that class with the option turned on, which gives the error:

> 'exampleProperty' is declared but its value is never read.(6133)

(I added a constructor and set the property, just so the error isn't mixed with / obscured by the error about it not being initialized.)

Comment: Yes, this would find the errors, but it would make the developer experience of creating new functions worse as the compiler would start failing on them. That's the reason why I would rather have it as a linter rule. Thanks for the answer though, it helped me clean up the project of places where we already had left these unwanted functions

Comment: @ViliusGudžiūnas - Yeah, it would be nice if this could be just a warning, not an error, like with a couple of the other options. Doesn't seem to be the case with this one though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using true `#` private class fields, the core ESLint rule [`no-unused-private-class-members`](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unused-private-class-members) will detect unused ones.

For TypeScript `private` type privacy, there is no such rule right now. But there is an [open typescript-eslint issue to augment `no-unused-private-class members`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/4571) that's accepting PRs. Meaning: if you can code it right, it'd be accepted into typescript-eslint.